# python define tk.StringVar() as a global variable to call the method which update this Variable from another file

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global

i have a problem with the tk.StringVar in my GUI. I want to update the StringVar with a method from another file. If im trying in the same class it works fine, but as soon as i call the method from another function, because im getting the prediction from our model from this file, i want to display the predicition in my GUI, im getting an AttributeError that my VoiceRecorder does not have a attribute with the name phonological_var. I know i initialize the phonological_var in the launch method and that is the problem, but if i initialize it e.g the **init**() or out of the scope of the class it is either too early to define a tk.StringVar or if im setting in to None it is not a tk.StringVar variable anymore and in the publish_emotion_label the phonological_var does not have a .set function logically.

this is my code:

```
import os
import wave
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import pyaudio
import numpy as np


audio_array = []


class VoiceRecorder:


def launch(self):
    self.window = tk.Tk()

    self.window.geometry("1000x650")
    self.window.title("Emotional Recognition through Speech")

    self.phonological_var = tk.StringVar()
    self.linguistic_var = tk.StringVar()


    self.phonological_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Phonological Prediction",font=("Robot", 18) )
    self.phonological_label.pack()

    self.phonological_prediction = tk.Label(self.window, borderwidth=2, relief="groove", textvariable=self.phonological_var,
                                            width=15, height=3, font=("Robot", 10))
    self.phonological_prediction.pack()


    self.linguistic_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Linguistic Prediction",  font=("Robot", 18))
    self.linguistic_label.pack()

    self.linguistic_prediction = tk.Label(self.window,borderwidth=2, relief="groove",  textvariable=self.linguistic_var,
                                          width=15, height=3, font=("Robot", 10))
    self.linguistic_prediction.pack()




    self.recording = False
    self.window.mainloop()



def record_signal(self):
    if self.recording:
        self.recording = False
        self.button.config(fg="black")
    else:
        self.recording = True
        self.button.config(fg="red")
        print("Record started")
        threading.Thread(target=self.record).start()



def record(self):
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000,
                        input=True, frames_per_buffer=512)


    start = time.time()

    while self.recording:
        #read the data from the stream
        audio_data = stream.read(1024)
        audio_array.append(np.frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=np.float32))



        passed = time.time() - start

        secs = passed % 60
        mins = passed // 60
        self.time_label.config(text=f"{int(mins):02d}:{int(secs):02d}")

        if passed >= 5:
            self.recording = False
            self.button.config(fg="black")
            #only for testing
            #self.publish_emotion_label("hallo", "moin")

    print("Record stopped")
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()

    audio_array_converted = np.concatenate(audio_array)

    from main_ser import add_data_to_queue
    add_data_to_queue(audio_array_converted)




def publish_emotion_label(self, prediction_1, prediction_2):


    self.phonological_var.set(prediction_1)
    self.linguistic_var.set(prediction_2)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    vc = VoiceRecorder()
    vc.launch()
```

How could i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try paring this down to a [mre]